# How to have PyCharm show the tables in a Django SQLite database?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm not very familiar with Django (I've used more Flask, Web.py, and Falcon), and one thing that I'm finding strange is that when I look at the 'Database' tab in PyCharm, I don't see a list of all of the tables that seem to be getting used in the database:

[image]

If I use `python manage.py dbshell` to start a sqlite3 session and then type `.tables`, this is the list of tables that I see:

[image]

How do I get those tables to be browsable from within the PyCharm database viewer?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the refresh button in the Database panel? I've found PyCharm is occasionally a little bit slow on the uptake there.

Comment: Secondly, are you sure `local.db` is the correct database?

Comment: @AKX that was it, I needed to right-click on the db and select 'Synchronize'.  Feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept / upvote it.

Comment: @AKX or if you think this question should be deleted, I'm OK with that too.

Comment: posted as answer. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer:

PyCharm is occasionally a little slow on the uptake for new tables.

The Refresh/Synchronize button on the Database panel usually fixes that.